# No data is retrieved from Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.6 and python 3.6.  I am quite new to django and python, trying to make a blog. I am not able to retrieve the data from database. Even though it is there in database

my model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
          STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published','Published'), )

          title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
          slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
          author = models.ForeignKey(
                          User,
                          blank=True,
                          null=True, )
          body = models.TextField()
          publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
          created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
          updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
          status = models.CharField(
          max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
          objects = models.Manager()  # The default manager
          published = PublishedManager()  # custom manager

          class Meta:
             ordering = ('-publish', )

          def __str__(self):
            return self.title

          def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse(
                      'blog:post_detail',
                       args=[
                       self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                       self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug
        ])
```

view which handles this model is

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_list_or_404(
      Post,
      slug=post,
      status='published',
      publish__year=year,
      publish__month=month,
      publish__day=day)

    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

when us the html template for getting data

```
  <p>Published {{ post.pulish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
```

The output is just
                " Published by"

But when I use just

```
  {{ posts }}
```

I getting output

```html
[<Post: this is Me>]
```

**"this is Me "** is the title of post saved in database

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.It would be great help if you inform me what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you getting the list of `Post` objects so you should iterrate through the list of posts in the template like so

```
{% for post in posts %}

    < your stuff here >

{% endfor %}
```

if you don't want to iterrate through the list of `Post` objects you should either get one `Post` object in your view:

```
post = get_object_or_404(
  Post,
  slug=post,
  status='published',
  publish__year=year,
  publish__month=month,
  publish__day=day)
```

or in your template get object by index:

```
<p>Published {{ post.0.publish }} by {{ post.0.author }}</p>
```

where `0` is the index of the record

Answer (score 3):

your HTML template needs to iterate through the result set (even if there is only a single post)

```
{% for post in posts %}

    <p>Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

And it should be `publish` instead of pulish

Or if you don't want to iterate through result set you can do

`<p>Published {{ post.0.publish }} by {{ post.0.author }}</p>`

where `0` is the index of the first record.

This is because databases always return what's known as a resultset - a collection of rows regardless of what programming language you use. So this approach is needed.

Comment: or if you don't want to iterate through result set you could do `<p>Published {{ post.0.publish }} by {{ post.0.author }}</p>` where 0 is the index

Comment: yes @latsha but it wasn't clear from the question whether he wanted to display just one or all so I left it like this.

Comment: Thanks you, it helped .I just need to  display just one ,so sorry about that . But I am curious why is there a need for such an iteration

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote loop in code

you should use for loop for retrieving data regardless of how many entries in your db

```
{% for post in posts %}

< your stuff here >

{% endfor %}
```